# Removing focus from a button in Edge

Tags: jquery, html, focus, microsoft-edge

I need to remove the lingering focus of a button after it's clicked. I was able to accomplish this in Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox using

`$("#myButton").blur();`

But this doesn't seem to work in Microsoft Edge. Is there a way to do the equivalent?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/activeElement *"When there is no selection, the active element is the page's <body> or null."* so change the activeElement back to body or null.

Comment: @KevinB That worked, thank you!